# Can you use the Skilled feat to gain proficiency with a musical instrument?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, proficiency

The [Skilled](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/skilled) feat (PHB, p. 170) says:

> You gain proficiency in any combination of three skills or tools of your choice.

I was wondering if I could use this feat to gain proficiency with a piano (a musical instrument), the Performance skill, and another skill.

Comment: @Jason_c_o: ...It says it in the feat description... I've edited in a quote now.

Comment: @V2Blast Right, I was just trying to guide the new user to add more information. I know what the feat does.

Comment: If you get a response that answers your question, please confirm it as the answer. That way everyone knows you aren't looking for more input. :)

Answer (score 12):

### Yes

Musical instruments are [a kind of tool](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/equipment#Tools). The Skilled feat lets you gain proficiency with tools. Therefore Skilled lets you gain proficiency with a type of musical instrument.

Note: When picking an instrument, make sure to talk to your DM to ensure you'll actually get to use it. There's no point in proficiency with Pipe Organs if your character never finds a pipe organ to play.

Comment: "There's no point in proficiency with Pipe Organs if your character never finds a pipe organ to play." - in addition, something like a pipe organ is too large to carry around easily, so even if you do have proficiency in it, you would probably specifically need to find one every time you want to play one.

Comment: Also, it might be worth pointing to the [relevant section of the basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/equipment#Tools) when stating that musical instruments are counted as tools; they are listed alongside artisan's tools, gaming sets, and "other tools" (and according to the PHB, land and water vehicles) for the purposes of tool proficiencies.

Comment: Thanks guys! I must've skipped this part, I'll read things more thoroughly from now on HAHA

Comment: Musical instrument proficiencies are weirdly specific compared to others like Alchemists' Tools which imply a very broad knowledge of a whole bunch of stuff. Seems like it'd be better to have "keyboards", "strings", "percussion", etc., and allow a player to understand both pipe organs and pianos.

Comment: @mattdm They're also specific in use.  It's difficult to tell what I'd use for a check.  Should I use Intelligence, Charisma, or Dexterity?  How does Performance come into play?  If I have expertise in Performance, would I have done better if I just sung the song?  Is singing considered Performance or a musical instrument?  Personally, I'd just have Performance be the primary skill, and having a proficiency with an instrument just gives you Expertise when used during your Performance check.

Comment: @DanielZastoupil If you're going to use Performance, have the proficient instrument provide Advantage. Among other things, most music focused characters will probably have acquired Expertise with Performance already, and Advantage *doesn't* change the success range.